# Autocomplet is not working with two values at the same time in Angular?

Tags: angular, autocomplete

Trying to **Autocomplete textbox with two values** - **i.e. Publication and city** but autocompletes is only working to publication not city. like you can see in image blow test is publication and Delhi is city but it only work till publication if I enter **publication and city together is not working**

**example:** if i enter test, it will show test but when i search test -delhi exactly same it won't show test -delhi from autocorrect.

[image: interface]

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-field col-lg-12 ">
<label class="label" for="company">Publication</label>

<input [(ngModel)]="pubTitleKeyUp" (ngModelChange)="keyUpPublication(pubTitleKeyUp)" name="pub"
    class="input-text js-input" type="text" required autocomplete="off">

<div class="search-result" *ngIf="publications" style="max-height: 120px;">
<ul style="margin:0; padding:5px;">
<li *ngFor="let pub of publications">
<a (click)="onClickPublication(pub)"> {{ pub.Title }} -{{ pub.city }} </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
    keyUpPublication(e) {
    let k = e as string
    let kl = k.length

    this.publications = this.allPubs.filter(p => {
      let title = p.Title.toLowerCase()
      return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase()
    })
  }

  onClickPublication(pub: IPub) {
    this.pubTitleKeyUp = pub.Title + '-' + pub.city;
    this.selectedPub = pub
    this.publications = []
  }
```

Comment: Your issue isn't entirely clear. Could you share the exact inputfor the problem, and explain what the expected result is? By the way, it looks like you have an extraneous space in "Test -Delhi". Don't know if that will make a difference.

Comment: As opposed to using the `substring` approach, have you tried `includes`? `substring`'s end index is exclusive, so removes the final letter if you use your approach.

Comment: can you elaborate or show exact what are you suggesting in snippet ?

Comment: `return title.includes(k.toLowerCase())`

Comment: yes I tried this but no help

Comment: Can you create stackblitz demo so I can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your filter. You are filtering only on `title` and not on city. If you are searching in format of your `li` text then I would suggest following

```
 this.publications = this.allPubs.filter(p => {
  let title = p.Title + '-' + p.city;
  return title.toLowerCase().includes(k.toLowerCase());
})
```

Comment: It resolve my issue I need to put `' -'` just extra space also in it, thank you :)